# How to prevent LAN overload triggered by running Win10 in a Parallels VM?

Tags: network, macos, parallels-desktop

I have a strange problem on our LAN. Recently we included a Mac with macOS Sierra (10.12.6), and it has installed a Parallels VM with Win10. Our network speed is 50/50 Mbps, but every time the Win10 VM is started in that Mac speed drops to around 1Mbps download, and all other computers in LAN are no longer capable to perform some standard office online work.

Is it possible to limit the network card to for example 30Mbps so other computers can continue with performing their tasks?

Comment: Limiting network bandwidth seems a rather drastic measure, might make more sense to solve the root cause here. How is network access configured for this VM? What kind of network activity is Win10 initiating once it starts?

Comment: Network mode for this system was set to Shared, and that resulted in internet speed to dropping to 1Mbps, now I set it to Bridged: Default Adapter and it seems a bit better, speed goes around 10Mbps, and in some short time intervals goes to 5 - 3 Mbps. I turned of lot of services in windows to prevent and useless data flow, but still.... I figured, since Windows is used only for a couple of hours, sometimes, to limit data usage in that period and when parallels is off, just return to normal settings for network adapter....

Comment: A few questions....your *network* speed is 50/50?  Do you mean your Internet is 50MB up and 50MB down?  Your network speed should be 10/100/1000.   The next question is whether this is a Parallels or a guest OS issue.  Can you load up a new Parallels VM with a fresh install of Win10 in it to see if the problem continues?  Finally, what do you have running in this Win10 VM?  Win10 doesn't just start downloading to the extent it kills bandwidth.